# Dynamic return type based on object property using string literal in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I want to be able to have a dynamic return type based on the string literal passed in.

Current implementation:

```
type Baseball = {
 name: string;
 lng: number;
 lat: number;
}

type SeriesInfo = {
  series: {
    [key: string]: Baseball;
  };
};

class BaseballInfo {
    private data: SeriesInfo;
    constructor() {
        this.data = {
            'series': {
                mets:  { name: 'Mets', lng: 12.34, lat: 12.34 },
                yankees:  { name: 'Yankees', lng: 12.34, lat: 12.34 },
            }
      }
  }
  // ...
  public getName(key: string) {
    return this.getProperty(key, 'name') as Baseball['name'];
  }
  private getProperty(key: string, prop: keyof Baseball) {
    return this.data.series[key][prop];
  }
}
```

I want to be able to dynamically set the return type to instead do something like this:

```
  public getName(key: string) {
    return this.getProperty(key, 'name');
  }

  private getProperty(key: string, prop: keyof Baseball) {
    return this.data.series[key][prop] as Baseball[prop];
  }
```

Comment: Please consider editing the above code to constitute a [mcve] as described by [ask]. RIght now the `series` property is not declared so I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do.  It might be as simple as making `getProperty()` generic as in `private getProperty<K extends keyof Baseball>(key: string, prop: K) { return this.series[key][prop] };` but without `series` defined I can't be certain.

Comment: @jcalz is that more clear?

Comment: Is is possibly to dynamically set the type of `this.series[key][prop]` to be either only be a string or a number?

Comment: Your `series` is now defined but... incorrectly?  Try your code in a standalone IDE like [the Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play).  I think `SeriesInfo` should probably just be `{[k: string]: Baseball}` and not `{series: {[k: string]: BaseballInfo}`.

Comment: I'm sure what you want is possible but I'd really love to know that I'm dealing with the correct types here before I write up an answer.

Comment: @jcalz updated after validating it on the playground

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the easiest way to get the behavior you're asking for is to make `getProperty()` a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) function in `K`, a subtype of `keyof Baseball` which will be inferred when you call it.  The return type of this function is inferred by the compiler to be `Baseball[K]`, which is a generic [lookup type](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-1.html#keyof-and-lookup-types) representing the type of the `K`-keyed property of a value of type `BaseBall`:

```
private getProperty<K extends keyof Baseball>(key: string, prop: K) {
  return this.data.series[key][prop];
}
```

---

The only other thing I'd mention here is that `SeriesInfo`'s [index signature](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#indexable-types) implies that it will have a `Baseball`-typed property for *any* key you use, but of course this is very unlikely to be true, and in actuality most keys will return an `undefined` property, leading to apparently-fine code at design time that blows up at runtime:

```
new BaseballInfo().getName("red sox").toUpperCase(); // TS: okay, JS: error!
```

That's just the way index signatures work (see [microsoft/TypeScript#13778](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13778)).  I'm not sure how you want to address this.  One way is to have `getProperty()` return a value *or* `undefined`, if the key isn't present. If so, I'd change your types like this:

```
type SeriesInfo = {
  series: {
    [key: string]: Baseball | undefined;
  };
};
```

to acknowledge the `undefined` possibility, and then use the [optional chaining](http://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#optional-chaining) operator (or similar) inside `getProperty()`:

```
private getProperty<K extends keyof Baseball>(key: string, prop: K) {
  return this.data.series[key]?.[prop]; // notice the ?. operator
}
```

Now `getProperty()` returns `Baseball[K] | undefined` and `getName()` returns `string | undefined` and the following code is now an error:

```
new BaseballInfo().getName("red sox").toUpperCase(); // error!
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- possibly undefined
```

---

**Or**, you can just be more specific about the type of `series` by allowing the compiler to infer what the keys are, and then only allow those keys to be passed in, by adding another generic parameter:

```
  type Series = BaseballInfo['data']['series'];

  class BaseballInfo {
    private data = {
      'series': {
        mets: { name: 'Mets', lng: 12.34, lat: 12.34 },
        yankees: { name: 'Yankees', lng: 12.34, lat: 12.34 },
      }
    };
    constructor() { }
    public getName<S extends keyof Series>(key: S) {
      return this.getProperty(key, 'name');
    }
    private getProperty<S extends keyof Series, B extends keyof Baseball>(key: S, prop: B) {
      return this.data.series[key][prop];
    }
  }
```

And now the error looks like this:

```
  new BaseballInfo().getName("red sox").toUpperCase(); // error!
  // ----------------------> ~~~~~~~~~
  // "red sox" is not assignable to "yankees" | "mets"
```

---

Okay, hope that helps.  Good luck!

[Playground link to code](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#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-OtQuGYPFDUzrEJiAB3H0pOqDebrBW8yAzABEEtIUE8zqbc3WUwwMDVAGFffN5EgAPRjp1oFVoACEQgnSAAfivV2v1xvNxukLaALS7pAwTyVAisuhZHKEYjYGwMii62AIZAAFQIsmW5rQglsDGYvtSvACGKmKPEKcQKBcKhqCIZi6IaEKmNocFWKUtC-o4zjQD4NQAYMoQHFsIAHPE+FpqchaoeUrBVDh1YeN4wEmmanTdLstJHJhpznJcVxvLcGK6k8rzvES0HQmShgUiSMJwgiPHIqiEDomQIFPHiinQJ83xiVS5KQuJ1JySETLUCUBjwKM4yTNM8wYiZh4smyHL1g8toOE6roQO6SCet6fQnIGAq9NG+yxvGspJpaKpqhqArarq+pFsabQdJybxWjFdBuR5brYB6URehh-RfEwOVeXlPkFd6tEBkGvRhtFSQhSEYXShFGyEamnEZnQJH5hRjIoaWEAVjV9T0bWLmNi2JCSB2XY9p4faDsOBrjpOugzvO1CLvue37Qdh37v6y5bguk4zW281IGsIieDQSDUW+oCssgUxIE2CkEk2GQfdcUBNreQA)

Answer (score 2):

Specify getProperty as:

```
  private getProperty<T extends keyof Baseball>(key: string, prop: T): Baseball[T] {
    return this.data.series[key][prop];
  }
```

Now getName is correctly typed as string.